# Python: Find index by range in multidimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm newbie in python. I have this list for example:

```
[[1, 10],[11, 20],[21,30]]
```

Then I have a number 17. How can I find index by range. Number 17 is between 11 and 20. Index will be 1. I can do it with loop. Is there a way without loop by built in function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like the simplest way to do what you need to:

```
ranges = [[1, 10],[11, 20],[21,30]]
n = 17
for i, r in enumerate(ranges):
    if n in range(r[0], r[1]+1):
        print(i)
        break
```

Btw, for the kind of ranges you have, you can go for a more mathematical approach:

```
index = (n-1) // 10
```

Comment: Thx for a quick answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` combined with `next`:

```
ranges = [[1, 10],[11, 20],[21,30]]
target = 17

target_range = next(filter(lambda range: range[0] < target < range[1], ranges))
```

`target_range` will be `[11, 20]` in this case.

`filter` here is responsible for excluding ranges that do not have `target` within them. And assuming that the ranges do not overlap, `filter` will exclude every range but one, and we can get that one with `next`.

You can also change up the criteria for what ranges are kept. If you consider `11` part of `[11, 20]` (right on the border), you can do `range[0] <= target <= range[1]` instead.

Comment: Not sure if this will be suitable for a "newbie" in python but good answer :)

Comment: Thx for a quick answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use generator expression.

```
>>> def find_index_by_range(*, collection, target):
...     return next(
...         (index for index, value in enumerate(collection) if target in range(*value)),
...         None,
...     )
...

>>> ranges = [[1, 10],[11, 20],[21,30]]
>>> find_index_by_range(collection=ranges, target=17)
1
>>> find_index_by_range(collection=ranges, target=28)
2
```

Comment: Thx for a quick answer